# React Native iOS Release Crash: Image not found

Tags: react-native, xcode13, dyld

First of all, I'm new to Xcode and iOS development.

I am building a React Native app, and I am running into trouble when running a release on a physical device. I am able to build and install to the device, but upon running the app, it crashes after opening the splash screen. This is only happening on release.

After poking around, I was able to find:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/hermes.framework/hermes
>
> ...
> Reason: Image not found

[See screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhCaH.png)

I would assume that this is an image asset linking error, but wouldn't React Native and Cocoapods take care of such references?

Still learning here. Any help would be appreciated.